# codeigniter : error in sending email

Tags: codeigniter

I am beginner to the codeigniter,i want to send an email from codeigniter to gmail,code is like below,

email configuration in email. controller

```
        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.google.email.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'manju.gate2013@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '*****'
            );
```

then i load the library

```
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
```

then i passe the required data from,to,password,subject and message to email library,

```
        $this->email->from('manju.gate2013@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to('manjunath861@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('this is testing email');
        $this->email->message('It is working');
```

and finally i check whether my email is sent or not by using fallowing condition

```
        if($this->email->send()==true){

            echo "your mail was sent";
        }
        else{
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

Comment: So what you got ? I mean error message ?

Comment: Refer to answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855016/unable-to-send-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'Your email address';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'Your Password';

$this->email->initialize($config);
if($this->email->send()==true){

    echo "your mail was sent";
}
else{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

If you are sending mail from **localhost** than you can use this but if you are sending from **server** than you don't need to use this **SMTP Config**

Answer (score 1):

You typed the server URL in wrong.  It should be:

> ssl://smtp.googlemail.com