# Unable to send email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In the below codeigniter i want to send a email but i cant send it pls help me.

```
 <?php

/**
* SENDS EMAIL WITH GMAIL
*/
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
    function index() 
    {   
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'sltechdevelop@gmail.com ',
            'smtp_pass' => 'highschool',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
            );
         $this->load->library('email', $config);
         $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

         $this->email->from('sltechdevelop@gmail.com', 'moses');
         $this->email->to('sltechdevelop@gmail.com');       
         $this->email->subject('This is an email test');        
         $this->email->message('It is working. Great!');
         if($this->email->send())
         {
        echo 'Your email was sent, successfully.';
         }
         else
         {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
          }
    }
}
?>
```

It is showing error

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 65272624 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:
to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA
data: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 16:54:03 +0000 From: "moses" Return-Path: To: sltechdevelop@gmail.com Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?This_is_an_email_test?= Reply-To: "sltechdevelop@gmail.com" X-Sender: sltechdevelop@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <5238892bc2bad@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5238892bc2bbc" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_5238892bc2bbc Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit It is working. Great! --B_ALT_5238892bc2bbc Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable It is working. Great! --B_ALT_5238892bc2bbc--
Unable to send data: .
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564400/send-email-by-email-class-in-codeigniter-with-gmail

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_auth' => true,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

See here for details:http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132443/

Comment: i have edited the code but still the error is not solved i got  fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Answer (score 2):

Enable: `php_openssl.dll` from php.ini, present in your php folder

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config = array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.secureserver.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_auth' => true,
          'smtp_user' => 'uername',
          'smtp_pass' => 'password',
          'mailtype' => 'html',
          'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
          );
          $this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers.  Please add detail of what you are doing.

Comment: @remya are you trying to get the graveyard title